# Is it possible to implement iPhone push notifications in a Google App Engine application?

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm in the planning phase of an iPhone application and am considering using [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) for my server component due to its scalability features.

Push notifications are sent using a binary interface to `gateway.push.apple.com:2195`.

However, the JRE for the server is only allowed to use the [following standard classes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html), which does not include the `Socket` classes. Can `URLConnection` be used somehow to do this?

**Is there a way to implement push notifications given the restrictions on Google App Engine applications?**

*I'd like to avoid using a third-party service such as [AppNotify](http://appnotify.com/) or [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com/push/) if possible.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now with [Appengine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes) Release 1.7.7 its possible!

Answer (score 24):

Nope.  Google App Engine forbids native socket connections.  You either need to use a third party service (like the ones you mentioned) or have another dedicated server for sending notifications.

EDIT:  Please note that the limitation of GAE on sockets and outgoing calls isn't a library limitation only.  Google servers actually block all outbound network connections; they only allow HTTP requests through URL Fetching servers.

If you like, you can star [Issue 1164: Add Support for Apple Push Notification Service](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1164).

Comment: Thank you for the Issue link. This would be a great feature to add!

Comment: @notnoop That is no longer true, see the other answer. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lately, Google officially supports to send push notification on iOS. You can take a look at this [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java).

For more detail, checkout this Google's [post](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/07/google-app-engine-takes-pain-out-of-sending-ios-push-notifications.html).

Answer (score 0):

You use the 3rd-party library [notnoop/java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns). It is easy to use. The only problem you could meet is **the thread limitation on the GAE**

You could refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900789/474002

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible. Check out [java-apns-gae](https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/java-apns-gae).

It's an open-source, Java APNS library that was specifically designed to work (and be used) on Google App Engine.