# Google App Engine APNS

Tags: google-app-engine, apple-push-notifications

Im developing the server side for an iOS app with Google App Engine and JDO in Java, and I just realized that GAE dont support Apple Push Notification Service, and I`m very frustrated.

I have been seen quite of solutions like Urban Airship, xtify, etc; but It`s too expensive if I reach to have an important amount of users.

Besides, I have been investigating about Javapns and similars, but GAE don`t support BouncyCastle either.

I want to know if there is a free or low cost solution for support APNS in my GAE server, because I can`t pay 200 $ per month. 
If there is not solution for my problem, would it been possible to build another server only for doing the Apple push notication with javapns, and that my GAE talks with it?

Answer (score 3):

I use the 3rd-party library [notnoop/java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns). It is easy to use. The only problem you could meet is **the thread limitation on the GAE** like below java exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
```

The issue is solved in the version [1.0.0.Beta3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.notnoop.apns/apns/1.0.0.Beta3) in the maven central. The detail solution is explained in this pull request [#162](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/pull/162).

So, the example code snippet to prepare and send push notification to APNs is like below, the key to solve the thread limitation is the method `withErrorDetectionThreadFactory` as below

```
// Prepare ApnsService
ClassPathResource certificate = new ClassPathResource("aps_production.p12");

ApnsService service = null;
try {
    service = APNS.newService()
      .withErrorDetectionThreadFactory(ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory()) // use GAE currentRequestThreadFactory
      .withCert(certificate.getInputStream(), certificatePassword)
      .withProductionDestination()
      .build();
} catch (InvalidSSLConfig | IOException e) {
    logger.warn("Fail to initialize APNs service");
}

// Send notification
String apnsPayload = APNS.newPayload()
    .alertBody("test alert")
    .badge(1)
    .sound("default")
    .customField("type", "general")
    .build();

service.push(<your device id>, apnsPayload);
```

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine now supports Sockets so you should be able to use a slightly modified version of javapns now.  I have successfully got PyAPNs working on AppEngine (python) which uses the new Socket functionality in 1.7.7.

If you are interested in seeing my python AppEngine project which does APNS, let me know and I will edit my answer with a link to it.  Every time I post a link to it here, a moderator deletes my answer for some reason

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread discussing this [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1164), and you can sign up for the sockets beta [here](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dF9QR3pnQ2pNa0dqalViSTZoenVkcHc6MQ#gid=0).

I've no idea if that will let you do what you want to do, but the people on the latter thread seem to think it will.

Comment: Thanks but it still is on beta phase, and I need in a short time. I have signed up but I don`t have any hope.

Comment: If you have an important amount of users it's unlikely that the free quota that GAE provide would be sufficient in any case. Yes, you can build another server that GAE talks to, of course.

Comment: Of course, but I dont want to build one server only for the Apple`s notifications. I am searching a way to make the APNS in GAE, but I dont know if Urban Airship is free for a small amount of users or if my server will get a lot of user with too many notifications (I am building a chat, so if I write a message, a notification must be send to the other person). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need it for chat, trying thinking of posting the push notifications internally from the client itself (while your server providing the push tokens of your friends). It can fit well to your chat propose.

Answer (score 0):

Appengine now supports sockets in 1.7.7 so you can use APNS.  The java runtime can use the java-apns lib with a minor modification.  [Here is a blogpost on the modifications needed](http://googleappenginetutorial.blogspot.com/2013/04/java-apns-on-appengine.html).

Answer (score 0):

a very good news indeed .... official support now available no more in beta

http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.in/2013/07/google-app-engine-takes-pain-out-of-sending-ios-push-notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

Google officially supports iOs push notification. You can take a look at this sample code: [ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java) and Google's post: [Google app engine takes pain out of sending ios push notifications](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/07/google-app-engine-takes-pain-out-of-sending-ios-push-notifications.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may check out `java-apns-gae`.

It's an [open-source Java APNS library](https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/java-apns-gae) that was specifically designed to work (and be used) on Google App Engine.