# Are there any benefits to using a push notification provider?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am building an app that needs to use push notifications. Currently it is only an iPhone app and i have already implemented a manual version for push notifications.

There are quite a few services that do this kindof thing for you... Are there any benefits to using them?  Having a nice API is not really relevant because of the fact that i have already implemented pushing manually.

The main reason i ask is that i downloaded the app Path and noticed that their push notifications seem to be a lot faster and a lot more reliable than my app...

Btw, Im using GAE for the backend.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious: How did you implement push notifications on App Engine? I thought [that wasn't possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811439/is-it-possible-to-implement-iphone-push-notifications-in-a-google-app-engine-app). Or does GAE stand for something else?

Comment: Technically it isnt possible, what I did was use 2 servers -- one on GAE, and the other is a app engine dev server running on a VHS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious benefit to using a push notification provider is not having to write the code yourself. Writing an efficient and reliable provider of Apple Push Notifications is not simple. If you want a quick solution and are willing to pay for it, using an existing provider is probably the way to go.

In my opinion the APNS API is bad. The fact that you don't get an acknowledgement for a successfull notification makes it hard to code a reliable provider. If you want to make sure you're not missing error responses from Apple, you have to attempt reading often from the connection, and with large timeouts, which will make your provider slow. On the other hand, if you want to send your notifications as quickly as possible, you'll have to sacrifice the reliability (because you won't be able to rely on getting all the error responses that Apple send). Of course, if you make sure that your DB doesn't contain invalid device tokens, and that you always send valid payloads, you can assume that you won't get error responses from Apple, which would allow you to send notifications quickly.

That said, I'm not sure how reliable and/or fast are the existing APN providers.
The best way to be sure of the quality of the provider you use is to write it yourself (unless you are willing to spend the time on testing the reliabily and speed of existing providers).